# Adding comma makes python object as Tuple

Tags: python, class

Can you please explain one behavioral in Python.
I have defined some server class

```
class Server:
...
```

Now when I crate object from it:

```
s=Server("logiclic1","master","10.97.113.161", "00:50:56:80:6D:4C", ["logiclic2","logiclic3"])
print type(s)
```

Return value is correct: `<type 'instance'>`

However, when I add comma at the end:

```
s=Server("logiclic1","master","10.97.113.161", "00:50:56:80:6D:4C", ["logiclic2","logiclic3"]),
print type(s)
```

Return object becomes tuple: `<type 'tuple'>`

Can someone please explain what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

`tuple`s (aside from the empty `tuple`) are defined by commas, not parentheses as most people think; a trailing comma is in fact the only way to *directly* make a one-element `tuple`. Parentheses are optional unless the lack of parentheses would create ambiguity, so:

```
x = 1,
```

and:

```
x = (1,)
```

both mean the same thing, creating a `tuple` with a single element, `1`. In much the same way that surrounding your constructor call with `[]` would make it create a one-element `list` containing the object, the trailing comma makes it create a one-element `tuple` containing the object.

Answer (score 2):

That's one (very Pythonic) way to create tuples in Python

It works when assigning variables of any type:

```
>>> a = "a"
>>> type(a)
<class 'str'>
>>> b = "b",
>>> type(b)
<class 'tuple'>
```